# How can I search a specific website for large list of keywords

Tags: web-crawler

I have a list of 500 companies. I need to know how many times each name appears on a specific website. It's not for SEO, it's to see if specific names are being mentioned right here on Stackoverflow.

Thanks 
T

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to write a web-crawler, as the tag you chose for your question implies. There are a couple of languages/frameworks that are naturally suited to this.

I myself like using Ruby for web-crawling applications. My gem bundle includes

```
Mechanize
Nokogiri
Anemone
```

Mechanize allows you to programmatically click on on-page elements like form submit buttons or pagination links. Nokogiri will allow you to parse the elements of a page using XML. Anemone utilizes Nokogiri and the Robots gem to allow you to crawl entire sites with just a few lines of code.

For a good introduction to web-scraping/crawling, I'd recommend the Bastard's Book of Ruby.

http://ruby.bastardsbook.com

Python also has some excellent libraries for scraping. You might want to get started with The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python [no, I don't make up the names] :) .

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

Or this guide to Web-Scraping 101

http://www.gregreda.com/2013/03/03/web-scraping-101-with-python/